# Not able to display data on button click in angular

Tags: angular, property-binding

- I have a button .on click of this button getInfo() method is
  called.
- This method calls a api and fetches resultData. Once resultData is
  available. i want some data to be displayed in a different div.
- Can someone advise

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="infobtn" (click)="getInfo()">Get info</button>
```

```
getInfo(){

------resultData

this.halfmoon = {
                 minvalue: 0,
                 maxvalue: 100,
                 value: resultData.data              
                };
}
```

i am doing this ,but the following is not working.

```
<div width="260" [data]="halfmoon" description="Product Two"></div>

``
```

Comment: Try `<div width="260" description="Product Two">{{halfmoon}}</div>`

Comment: try <div width="260" [innerHTML]="halfmoon" description="Product Two"></div>

Answer (score 0):

To display data, you should use [Angular's interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Your template should look like this:

```
<div width="260" description="Product Two">
    {{halfmoon.minValue}}, {{halfmoon.maxValue}}, {{halfmoon.value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What were you intending to achieve exactly? Just showing the data?

```html
<div width="260" description="Product Two">
  <pre>{{halfmoon | json}}</pre>
</div>
```